# F# Compiler Services incorrectly parses program

Tags: f#, f#-compiler-services

### UPDATE:

I now realize that the question was stupid, I should have just filed the issue. In hindsight, I don't see why I even asked this question.
The issue is here: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/issues/544

---

## Original question:

I'm using FSharp Compiler Services for parsing some F# code.
The particular piece of code that I'm facing right now is this:

```
  let f x y = x+y
  let g = f 1
  let h = (g 2) + 3
```

This program yields a TAST without the `(+)` call on the last line. That is, the compiler service returns TAST as if the last line was just `let h = g 2`.

**The question is:** is this is a legitimate bug that I ought to report or am I missing something?

---

## Some notes

1. [Here is a repo](https://github.com/fsoikin/FSharpCompilerServicesPlay/blob/master/run.fsx) containing minimal repro (I didn't want to include it in this question, because Compiler Services require quite a bit of dancing around).
2. [Adding more statements](https://github.com/fsoikin/FSharpCompilerServicesPlay/blob/master/run.fsx#L37) after the `let h` line does not change the outcome.
3. When compiled to IL (as opposed to parsed with Compiler Services), it seems to work as expected (e.g. see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FgMdUI))
4. [If I make `g` a value](https://github.com/fsoikin/FSharpCompilerServicesPlay/blob/master/run.fsx#L49), the program parses correctly.
5. [If I make `g` a normal function](https://github.com/fsoikin/FSharpCompilerServicesPlay/blob/master/run.fsx#L58) (rather than partially applied one), the program parses correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no priori experience with `FSharp.Compiler.Services` but nevertheless I did a small investigation using Visual Studio's debugger. I analyzed abstract syntax tree of following string:

```
            """
              module X

              let f x y = x+y
              let g = f 1
              let h = (g 2) + 3
            """
```

I've found out that there's following object inside it:

```
App (Val (op_Addition,NormalValUse,D:\file.fs (6,32--6,33) IsSynthetic=false),TType_forall ([T1; T2; T3],TType_fun (TType_var T1,TType_fun (...,...))),...,...,...)
```

As you can see, there's an addition in 6<sup>th</sup> line between characters 32 and 33.

The most likely explanation why F# Interactive doesn't display it properly is a bug in a library (maybe AST is in an inconsistent state or pretty-printing is broken). I think that you should file a bug in [project's issue tracker](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/issues).

UPDATE:

Aforementioned object can be obtained in a debbuger in a following way:

```
error.[0] 
(option of Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices.FSharpImplementationFileDeclaration.Entity) 
.Item2 
.[2]
(option of Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices.FSharpImplementationFileDeclaration.MemberOrFunctionOrValue)
.Item3
.f (private member)
.Value
(option of Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices.FSharpExprConvert.ConvExprOnDemand@903)
.expr
```